# Rails & CSS: best to have css for each controller or all in application.css?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

While semantically the code is cleaner if css for each controller is in it's separate css file, but wouldn't that mean several css asset files will be created when the user is browsing the site.

**For end-user's speed, wouldn't putting all css in application.css be better since the entire site's css would get loaded at once?**

Comment: That's exactly the role of the asset pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When developing in Rails the default environment is set to `Development`. In development Javascript and CSS files are served individually. When you switch to the production environment the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) compiles your CSS into a single `application.css` file. So only one CSS file is served from your `assets/stylesheets` (unless it's a vendor file).

Comment: Follow up question: if several controllers use the same css code, what's the best place to put it so even in development it works.

Comment: Personally, I think the way Rails handles CSS files is flawed.  I prefer not to generate the automatic files. I create my own structure. For example `layouts.css`, `utilities.css`, `mixins.css`, `sidebar.css`, etc... I also use SASS, which makes this task much easier.

Comment: Don't be afraid to create your own files.

Comment: If you're using the default `application.css` manifest, you should get all controllers' CSS files at all times. Many argue that this isn't the best way to organize your CSS though. (It may be better to base it on interface patterns than controllers, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the default css generator. Rails uses Pipelan minify or compress CSS/Javascript by defautl:

> Pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or compress JavaScript and CSS assets. It also adds the ability to write these assets in other languages such as CoffeeScript, Sass and ERB.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html